# SQL sub-query problem with grouping, average

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In MS Transact SQL, let's say I have a table (Orders) like this:

```
 Order Date       Order Total     Customer #
 09/30/2008       8.00            1
 09/15/2008       6.00            1
 09/01/2008       9.50            1
 09/01/2008       1.45            2
 09/16/2008       4.50            2
 09/17/2008       8.75            3
 09/18/2008       2.50            3
```

What I need out of this is: for each customer the average order amount for the most recent two orders.  So for Customer #1, I should get 7.00 (and not 7.83).

I've been staring at this for an hour now (inside a larger problem, which I've solved) and I think my brain has frozen.  Help for a simple problem?

Comment: can a customer have multiple orders in a day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should make it

```
select avg(total), customer 
from orders o1 
where orderdate in 
  ( select top 2 date 
    from orders o2 
    where o2.customer = o1.customer 
    order by date desc )
group by customer
```

Comment: May not work if there is more then 1 order on a given day e.g. if for a customer you have 3 orders on one day. the sub-query will give you 2 records of the same date, and the top query will take into account all 3 orders - but perhaps it is not real life scenario in the context.

Comment: In a real life scenario the date column would store the time too, so it wouldn't be a problem

Comment: You could also target the TOP 2 on the CreatedDate of the record, if your OrderDate has a "day resolution" only. If you have a CreatedDate, that is. ;-)

Comment: And if you don't, well, you don't have the data needed to get the last two sales, so you data schema is wrong

Comment: Actually, the Real Life version of this table has the resolution problem (dates, but not times) but it's close enough for the kind of information I need.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005 you have the RANK function, used with partition:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT i.ProductID, p.Name, i.LocationID, i.Quantity
    ,RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY i.LocationID ORDER BY i.Quantity DESC) AS 'RANK'
FROM Production.ProductInventory i 
    INNER JOIN Production.Product p 
        ON i.ProductID = p.ProductID
ORDER BY p.Name;
GO
```

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)

Comment: This has a touch of overkill. Is there a good reason to do it like that, performance-wise?

Comment: In terms of? There must be a damn good reason to divert from what a few lines less of standard SQL can do with an equal result.

Comment: Microsoft has provided a function (RANK with PARTITION) exactly to handle cases like these. The more specific a function, the better the execution plan.
So IMHO it's better in term of both future readability and performance.

Comment: The rank method is easier and much cleaner if there are multiple criteria that define the "rank" and the partition.  See /questions/150891/sql-query-remove-duplicates-with-caveats#151410 for an example where rank makes the query much simpler

Answer (score 0):

One option would be for you to use a cursor to loop through all the customer Id's, then do the averages as several subqueries.

Fair warning though, for large datasets, queries are not very efficient and can take a long time to process.